# Forum web scraper in Lua

Tags: performance, web-scraping, lua

I've written a short web scraper in Lua (run in LuaJIT for speed) to download every post from a specific forum (not general purpose... yet). It takes about 12 hours to run and download 500,000 posts and there are no errors. I'm wondering how I can make it faster. I know different places where the code can be *better* in readability and structure, but not how it could be better in speed.

````
local https = require("ssl.https")
local tcount, pcount = 0,0
local threads = {}
local posts = {}
local root = --the forum url

local output = io.open("output.txt", "a")

function scrape(address, p)
    local request_body = [[]]
    local response_body = {}

    local res, code, response_headers = https.request{
        url = address,
        method = "GET",
        source = ltn12.source.string(request_body),
        sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body),
    }

    if res ~= 1 or code ~= 200 then print(res, code) end

    if type(response_headers) == "table" and p then --if the function is called with a p param, print the response headers
        for k,v in pairs(response_headers) do
            print(k, v)
        end
    end
    if code == 301 then
        print("Location", response_headers["location"])
    end

    if type(response_body) == "table" then
        response_body = table.concat(response_body) --every response in this instance is a table, so I would probably be able to take out this if statement.
    else
        print("Not a table:", type(response_body))
    end
    return response_body
end

function parse_posts(response_body)
    for match in string.gmatch(response_body, '<div class="post%-body">.-</div>') do
        local m = string.gsub(match, '<span class="quote%-attr">.-</span>', ""):gsub([[</?[^>q]+>]], ""):gsub("\n", "<br>")
        output:write(m..'\n')
        pcount = pcount+1
    end
end

function get_threads(response_body)
    string.gsub(response_body, [[<a href="(/%d+/[^"]+)" class="title"]], function (m) local d = tonumber(m:match("%d+")) threads[d] = root..m end)
end

function get_pages(response_body, url)
    local p = 0
    string.gsub(response_body, [[class="btn mod%-page">(%d+)</a>]], function (m) if tonumber(m) > p then p = tonumber(m) end end)
    for i = p, 1, -1 do
        parse_posts(scrape(url.."/?page="..tostring(i)))
        --print("Scraping", url.."/?page="..tostring(i))
    end
end

do
    print("Getting threads")
    for i = 1528, 1, -1 do
        local url = root .. '/threads/?page='..tostring(i)
        get_threads(scrape(url))
    end
end

do
    print("Getting pages on each thread")
    for id,url in pairs(threads) do
        print("Writing for id", id)
        if id ~= 1121 and id ~= 1217 and id ~= 441 then     --exclude three specific large threads, i intend to remove this next iteration in favor of just removing them: threads[1121] = nil, but i do not believe that will improve speed at all.
            get_pages(scrape(url), url)
        end
        tcount = tcount+1
    end
end

print(string.format("Finished scraping %d posts across %d threads.", pcount, tcount))
output:close()
```
````

Comment: Would the user that voted down on this question please indicate in a comment why they voted down.

Comment: Out of interest how long does it take you to download an equivalent amount of data on your internet connection? I haven't looked at your code, but wonder if you may be optimising at the wrong side of a bottleneck

Comment: The entire txt post of everything I downloaded was like 120 MB, my internet DL speed is 73 Mbps, without doing the math, that definitely doesn't add to 12 hr run time.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the different sections of the program? (downloading vs. parsing, mostly)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I did not. I probably would try it but its been 6 months and I've lost interest / had no need of the project since I originally wrote it.